# KivyMD MDTextField not accepting any input

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying KivyMD to build an app and everything was working great until I ran into an issue which I can't seem to fix even after spending an entire day on it yesterday. I'm building an app in which I can store my workouts and ran into an issue when addeding two MDTextFields. First they wouldn't align properly and they moved all the way outside the boxlayout, then after some resizing (self.minimum_height in the KV file) they are now clickable (you can see the hint text changing), but they won't allow for any input. Can you anyone help me why the MDTextField aren't working? My guess it has something to do with the same issue which caused the fields to be moved outside the boxlayout, but I don't understand what is causing that issue.

Here is the modified KV:

```
NavigationLayout:
    id:nav_layout
    MainAppScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        AddWorkoutMenu:  

<MainAppScreenManager>

<AddWorkoutMenu>
    name: "addworkoutmenu"
    id: "addworkoutmenu"
    workoutname:workoutname
    setlist:setlist
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: "Add Workout"
            elevation: 10

        MDTextField:
            id: workoutname
            hint_text: "Workout name"

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: setlist
                Sets:
                    id: workoutboxlist

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            id:addset
            icon: "plus"
            text: "Add set"
            on_release:
                root.add_set()

<Sets>
    id:workoutbox
    workoutexerciselist:workoutexerciselist
    addbutton:addbutton
    reps:reps
    rest:rest
    orientation: "vertical"
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    radius: 15, 15, 15, 15
    padding: "16dp"
    spacing: "4dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        MDLabel:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: root.id


        MDIconButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
            icon: "trash-can"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            on_release:
                self.parent.parent.remove_set()

    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height / 4
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": 0}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        MDLabel:
            size_hint: (0.15,None)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Reps:"

        MDTextField:
            id: reps
            size_hint: (0.4,None)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.1}
            spacing: "4dp"
            current_hint_text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            line_color_normal: [1,1,1,1]
            hint_text: "# reps"

        MDLabel:
            size_hint: (0.1,None)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
            spacing: "4dp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Rest:"

        MDTextField:
            id: rest
            size_hint: (0.4,None)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.1}
            spacing: "4dp"
            current_hint_text_color: [1,1,1,1]
            line_color_normal: [1,1,1,1]
            hint_text: "in seconds"

    MDList:
        id:workoutexerciselist

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        id:addbutton
        icon: "plus"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: [1,1,1,1]
        text: "Add exercise"
        on_release:
            root.open_the_menu()


<WorkoutExerciseListItem>
    id: listitem
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: [1,1,1,1]
    DeleteItem:

<DeleteItem>
    name: "deleteicon"
    icon: "close"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: [1,1,1,1]
    on_release:
        root.remove()
```

Here is the modified Python:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList, IRightBodyTouch, OneLineRightIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu, RightContent
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from database import DataBaseExercises, DataBaseWorkouts


class AddWorkoutMenu(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddWorkoutMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def add_set(self):
        self.ids.setlist.add_widget(Sets(id = ""))
        for i in self.ids.setlist.children:
            if not hasattr(i, 'menu_1'):
                i.create_self()

    def save(self):
        workout = self.workoutname.text
        sets = self.ids.workoutboxlist._sets
        if workout != "":
            db_workouts.add(workout, sets)
            self.parent.current = "workouts"
            self.clear_all()
            toast("Exercise saved")
        else:
            toast("Please fill in all information")

    def clear_all(self):
        self.workoutname.text = ""
        for i in list(self.setlist.children):
            self.setlist.remove_widget(i)
        Sets._ids = 0
        self.add_set()

    def update_ids(self, removed, total):
        if removed != total:
            for i in self.ids.setlist.children:
                current_number = int(i.id[-1])
                if current_number > removed:
                    current_number -= 1
                    i.id = "Set " + str(current_number)


class Sets(MDBoxLayout):
    _ids = 0
    _sets = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sets, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Sets._ids += 1
        self.id = "Set " + str(Sets._ids)
        self._sets[self.id] = {}
        self._sets[self.id]["Exercise"] = []
        self._sets[self.id]["Reps"] = []
        self._sets[self.id]["Rest"] = []

    def add_selection(self, name):
        self.workoutexerciselist.add_widget(WorkoutExerciseListItem(text=name))
        self._sets[self.id]["Exercise"].append(name)
        print(self._sets[self.id]["Exercise"])
        self.update_height()

    def update_height(self):
        if self.workoutexerciselist.height == 16.0:
            self.workoutexerciselist.height = 0.0
        self.height = self.minimum_height + self.workoutexerciselist.height

    def create_menu(self, text, instance):
        menu_items = [{"text": i} for i in text]
        return MDDropdownMenu(position = "auto", caller=instance, items=menu_items, width_mult=5, callback=self.set_item)

    def create_self(self):
        exerciselist = db_exercise.get_all()
        self.menu_1 = self.create_menu(exerciselist, self.addbutton)

    def update_self(self, value):
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(value)
        for i in self.menu_1.items:
            for u in i.values():
                new_list.append(u)
        self.menu_1 = self.create_menu(new_list, self.addbutton)

    def set_item(self, instance):
        self.menu_1.on_dismiss()
        self.add_selection(instance.text)
        self.remove_item(instance.text)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        new_list = []
        for i in self.menu_1.items:
            for u in i.values():
                if u != item:
                    new_list.append(u)
        self.menu_1 = self.create_menu(new_list, self.addbutton)

    def open_the_menu(self):
        self.menu_1.open()

    def remove_set(self):
        number = int(self.id[-1])
        self._sets.pop("Set "+str(number))
        self.update_set(number)
        self.id = "Set 0"
        self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.update_ids(number, Sets._ids)
        Sets._ids -= 1
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)

    def update_set(self, number):
        for i in range(number, Sets._ids):
            self._sets["Set " + str(i)] = self._sets["Set " + str(i+1)]
            self._sets.pop("Set " + str(i + 1))

    def save_reps_and_rest(self):
        self._sets[self.id]["Reps"] = self.reps
        self._sets[self.id]["Rest"] = self.rest



class WorkoutExerciseListItem(OneLineRightIconListItem):
    pass


class DeleteItem(IRightBodyTouch, MDIconButton):
    pass

class MainAppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is happening, but adding:

```
        color_mode: 'custom'
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

to each `MDTextField` seems to wok.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly the answer!